# Class D Amplifier Design: Simulation(/Practical Design?) Issues

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, simulation, mosfet-driver, class-d

For a college project my project group needs to make a speaker amplifier. We need to use a +-15V PSU for the whole system and the amp must at least provide 15W to an 8 Ohm speaker. One of the components for this speaker amplifier is the power amplifier, which needs an input impedance of at least 50kOhm.

So we decided to go for a class D amplifier design because of the good efficiency. However this type of design is pretty complex, which I figured out after my simulation didn't went according to plan. This is the design I came up:
[image: Simulation of the class D amp in TINA SPICE]

The first part of the design is to ensure the input impedance is according to spec and to separate the positive waves from the negative waves. This is done with a voltage follower which has been connected to either a positive or negative 15V and to ground. Since this is done, it should clip at 0V and thus eliminate the positive or negative voltage. This is then fed into a comparator to make the positive or negative PWM sine wave which can be used to drive the MOSFETS. The MOSFETS have a cap connected to the voltage terminals to reduce voltage drops. This is then filtered to get the voltage and current amplified square wave back.

For the input two +-10V (Amplitude) sources where used, one a sine wave (1kHz) and the other a triangle wave (25kHz). Our goal is however to use +-15V sources by using a non-inverting amplifier to amplify the signal coming from the preamp.

However, the simulation shows something I didn't expect:
@SIN+:
[image: Supposed positive sine wave]
@TRI+:
[image: Supposed positive triangle wave]
This shows clipping at the positive edge and I'm not sure why the amp does this.

However, the simulation goes weirder:
@SIN-:
[image: Sine wave?]
@TRI-:
[image: Triangle wave?]

Not sure why this is happening, but I think TINA-TI SPICE is bugged af. So if anyone knows a good (free) alternative, I would love to hear about it.

Edit1:

So, I came up with a new plan:
[image: New Design]
In the old version I noticed that the TL072 are JFET opamps and this caused the clipping at the high voltage potential. Also, the MOSFETS were not oriented correctly.

I realised that I could also make a square wave when the sinus wave is high and then enable the triangle wave with an and gate. This idea works pretty good on the positive rail (red line), but I think I made a small mistake in the negative rail (green line)and I can't pinpoint it:
[image: PWM driver for MOSFETS]
I do see that the green line should be flipped from 0 to 15V (and the triangle wave should also be gone from 0 to 500m), but I'm not sure where I made a mistake.

Comment: Micro-cap 12 is a good free sim and contains many many libraries (since they decided to stop supporting it). BTW you won't get a 15 watt sinewave from +/-15 volt supplies into an 8 ohm load.

Comment: Probably also a good idea to research how previous Class D amplifiers have been built. There may be a basic misconception here about how rail to rail opamps actually work.

Comment: Surely you meant 10kHz, instead of 100kHz? Also, maybe try lower signals at the input, while avoiding overmodulation? Just some thoughts.

Comment: @Andyaka Will check it out, thanks! And I'm aware that I won't be able to get that due too the opamp current limitation

Comment: @BrianDrummond Hmm, looked into it and this does explain why the amp clips to ~12V and not 15V (voltage swing), but I still find it weird that it clips to the top voltage and not to ground (Or maybe the ~2V). Also, I tried looking for more information on class D amps but most info I can find on the internet will not be good enough for our report. The most interesting part seems to be the gate driver, so do you maybe have a recommendation for literature I could read on this subject or class D amps in general?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Just checked and this requirement is only for the opamps in the preamp, will update this in the question. Also, I noticed in a more simple simulation in falstad that only at 25*Fin the PWM modulation works